# fixing background position of an image in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

```
.Emoji
{
 cursor: pointer;
 float: right;
 height: 25px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-top: -21px;
  position: relative;
 right: -12px;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 23px;
 z-index: 40000;
 background-image: url("/images/globaleImg.png");
 background-position: -136px -387px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: auto auto;
}
```

in firefox and IE the position if the image is in right place but in chrome it's not 
[image]

in chrome it look like this :

[image]

how can i fix the class to suit both firefox and chrome without creating a new css file

Comment: can you create a fiddle or link your site? sometimes the problem is not with code

Comment: sadly i can't because the code is to big

Comment: just create a simplified version of your code, with the html and css associated with the issue. Without HTML we can't give you an accurate answer, it would just be guess work. [What I mean](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmlXU4uK5rA)

Answer (score 0):

It´s generally frowned on but sometimes necessary to have browser specific css:
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)

however i suggest building to firefox and chrome standards, then to IE as chrome and firefox are now collectively more used than IE, they are also more flexible